# How can I return the FLAGS register from a function?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to retrieve the FLAGS register in order to print it out for my "own-made" os (running on Bochs). Since I didn't find a way to force the printing of that register into the BOCHS log file, I am trying to print it out from my code.

Here is my attempt. (Disclaimer: I am a total ASM noob. Sorry for that ...)

```
u16int eflags()
{
  asm volatile ("pushf");
  asm volatile ("movw %esp-2, %eax");
}
```

Of course it does not compile. How can I turn the syntax into something correct please?

Comment: pushf; pop ax; Make sure the calling convention specifies that the return value is in the ax/eax register.

Comment: @James : this should be an answer, since it's both perfectly valid and correct.

Comment: @James Thank you James. It just work, and the calling convention uses indeed the eax register as the return value (in my case). Can you make it as an answer post? I would be glad to accept it of course. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pushf;
pop ax;
```

Make sure the calling convention specifies that the return value is in the ax/eax register.

Comment: You want `pop eax` in 32-bit mode, otherwise this unbalances the stack.